# The cookie with "X-Magento-Vary" cookieName couldn't be sent

Tags: magento2, cookie

I get **The cookie with "X-Magento-Vary" cookieName couldn't be sent**. if I try to open a previous order in the customer account.

[image]

Why is this happening?